# Custom HTTP Methods in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am trying to create a custom Spring MVC Controller for a resource that would handle the COPY HTTP method.

[@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) accepts only the following [RequestMethod](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html) values: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS and TRACE.

Is there any recommended way of handling custom HTTP methods in Spring MVC Controller?

Comment: You can override HTTP methods in Spring Boot 2.2.6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432464/2073804

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) allows only for `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS` or `TRACE` HTTP methods. This can be seen in the Apache Tomcat [implementation of the Servlet API](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/3c8b971d9b6fe48149ea4c483436615a1920c47a/java/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#L612-L675).

And this is reflected in the Spring API's [`RequestMethod` enumeration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html).

You can cheat your way around those by implementing your own `DispatcherServlet` overriding the `service` method to allow `COPY` HTTP method - changing it to POST method, and customize the [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) bean to allow it as well.

Something like this, using spring-boot:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class HttpMethods extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    public static class CopyMethodDispatcher extends DispatcherServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            if ("COPY".equals(request.getMethod())) {
                super.doPost(request, response);
            }
            else {
                super.service(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(HttpMethods.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/method")
    @ResponseBody
    public String customMethod(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getMethod();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setSupportedMethods("COPY", "POST", "GET"); // add all methods your controllers need to support

        return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new CopyMethodDispatcher();
    }
}
```

Now you can invoke the `/method` endpoint by using `COPY` HTTP method. Using `curl` this would be:

```
curl -v -X COPY http://localhost:8080/method
```

Comment: this does not work in latest Spring Boot Starter 2.2.5