# Spring MVC OPTIONS

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cors, http-options-method

I have a spring-boot 1.3.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT w/SpringSecurity project and I am concerned about security of the REST endpoints.  I have a CORS Filter defined:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

                registry.addMapping( "/**" ).allowedOrigins( "*" )
                        .allowedHeaders( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"          )       "x-requested-with" )
                        .allowedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedMethods("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
                        .maxAge( 3600);

            }

        };
    }
}
```

And I have a REST Controller:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class Controller extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/questions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        return questionService.getAllAvailableQuestions();
    }

  ...
}
```

But when I hit one of the endpoints with an OPTIONS call I get a result that appears to allow more than just the GET this endpoint defines:

```
Allow → GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control → no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length → 0
Date → Wed, 28 Oct 2015 16:32:12 GMT
Expires → 0
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-CSRF-HEADER → X-CSRF-TOKEN
X-CSRF-PARAM → _csrf
X-CSRF-TOKEN → 83983056-f904-449e-a215-fe9f9492866b
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff
X-Frame-Options → DENY
X-XSS-Protection → 1; mode=block
```

I thought Spring MVC would ignore OPTIONS call by default.  But I guess I also don't understand why I am seeing `Allow → GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH` being returned when I only allow GET for that call.  In the entire application I only allow GET, PUT, POST, DELETE so I don't know why the other values are returned, and what that means.  And most importantly, is this a security vulnerability?

Comment: Nothing in your question is about Spring Security so far. What does your call look like? Why should Spring ignore `OPTIONS` by default and how is that supposed to work with CORS, where `OPTIONS` is needed? What makes the response you get a security problem? And where and how did you define that only GET, PUT, POST, DELETE are allowed? `addCorsMappings` is only about CORS, nothing else.

Comment: Yea, I am still learning what all this means after going thru a security review.  I mentioned Spring Security because the project contains it and I thought it might be relevant to this topic.  I had done some research and read that OPTIONS was ignored by default, but perhaps that was a bad link.  In my CORS configuration I only allow those 4 methods, which is why I don't understand why the OPTIONS is saying that "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH" is allowed when CORS and my own REST endpoints don't use them all.

Comment: CORS is only relevant for browsers (i.e. AJAX!) and the CORS related response headers all start with `Access-Control-`. The controller can only handle `GET` requests for `/questions`. So if you don't have any other handler for that URL, an error will be returned for every other request method. And that's true for every request: No appropriate handler -> status 4xx.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me understand better.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at JavaDoc of `BaseFrameworkServlet#setDispatchOptionsRequest()` it contains following comment:

> Set whether this servlet should dispatch an HTTP OPTIONS request to the `#doService` method Default is "false", applying `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`'s default behavior (i.e. enumerating all standard HTTP request methods as a response to the OPTIONS request).

---

> But I guess I also don't understand why I am seeing Allow → GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH being returned when I only allow GET for that call.

As mentioned in the comment above, the request is not handled by Spring MVC dispatcher, but by `HttpServletRequest#doOptions`, which enumerates HTTP methods *the server supports* and knows nothing about your controller mapping.

If you want to verify this behavior you can put breakpoints in `DispatcherServlet`'s `doService` method and `HttpServlet`s `doOptions` method and see which one gets called. If you want OPTIONS request to be handled by the dispatcher, you can enable it using one of the ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331945/1291150).

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot application add to the **application.properties** file the following property:

```
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true
```

It will do the job.