# Request method 'OPTIONS' not supported - Spring Boot Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

I am using **Spring Boot** in the server side and **Angularjs** in client side, i configured **Spring Boot** application **CORS** using a **Filter** and it worked for **GET**, **POST** methods, but, when i tried to send **PUT** request using **$http** module, i got this in my browser console :

**Notice: url = http://localhost:8080/localbusinessusers/[object%20Object]**

> OPTIONS *url*
>   (anonymous function) @ angular.js:11442sendReq @
>   angular.js:11235serverRequest @ angular.js:10945processQueue @
>   angular.js:15552(anonymous function) @ angular.js:15568Scope.$eval @
>   angular.js:16820Scope.$digest @ angular.js:16636Scope.$apply @
>   angular.js:16928done @ angular.js:11266completeRequest @
>   angular.js:11464requestLoaded @ angular.js:11405 app.html:1
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   *url*. Response
>   for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 angular.js:11442 XHR
>   failed loading: PUT
>   "*url*".

And i got this on **Spring Boot console**:

> 2016-03-08 23:19:51.212  WARN 27044 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2]
>   o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'OPTIONS'
>   not supported

My **CORS** **Filter**:

```
package com.datcom.fouras;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with, X-Custom-Header");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My **REST** method in my **RestController**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/localbusinessusers", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public LocalBusinessUser update(LocalBusinessUser localBusinessUser) {
        log.debug("REST request to update a local business user : {}", localBusinessUser);
        if (localBusinessUser.getId() == null) {
            return save(localBusinessUser);
        } else {
            LocalBusinessUser localBusinessUser2 = localBusinessUserRepository.findOne(localBusinessUser.getId());
            localBusinessUser2 = localBusinessUser;
            return localBusinessUserRepository.saveAndFlush(localBusinessUser2);
        }
    }
```

And finally, my **$http** request:

```js
$http.put('http://localhost:8080/localbusinessusers/' + localBusinessUser)
                .success(function (data, status, headers) {
                    console.log('data: ' + data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                    console.log('data: ' + data);
                    console.log('status: ' + status);
                    console.log('header: ' + header);
                    console.log('config: ' + config);
                });
```

Notice:
PUT request is working using **Advanced REST Client**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Options requests are being prohibited, you can configure the `DispatcherServlet` to dispatch all options requests by adding this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true
```

For more information about options requests and Spring MVC using Spring Boot, there is a nice post for [Handling Options Request using Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331042/how-to-handle-http-options-requests-in-spring-boot)

You can also try the examples in this post for handling CORS and supporting Options requests by creating a simple controller to return NO_CONTENT for all Options requests: http://dontpanic.42.nl/2015/04/cors-with-spring-mvc.html

Comment: i edited my application.properties file but i still get the same errors

Comment: Did the NO_CONTENT options request controller help you?

Comment: Actually, i added these lines to application.properties file:                                          **# ENDPOINTS CORS CONFIGURATION (EndpointCorsProperties)
endpoints.cors.allow-credentials = false
endpoints.cors.allowed-headers = Content-Type, x-requested-with, X-Custom-Header
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods = *
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins = http://164.132.198.236, http://localhost
endpoints.cors.max-age = 3600**