# OPTIONS HTTP method instead of GET

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, ember.js, katharsis

I am new to ember js using version 3. From a route I am using this line 
    `this.get('store').findAll('users');`
  ***Instead of setting HTTP method GET, it is setting HTTP method OPTIONS.***

Because of server is getting OPTIONS as HTTP method, server side i am getting error.

> io.katharsis.errorhandling.exception.MethodNotFoundException: OPTIONS:
>   /users/

and in browser I am getting this error

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I am having the below code in application adapter and @CrossOrigin(origins="*") on Spring Rest API side.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({

init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.set('headers', {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
  },

  host: 'http://localhost:8082',
  namespace: 'spring-katharsis'
});
```

If the request contain HTTP method GET, I think it may solve the issue.

Please help on this.

Comment: Have you tried authenticating at the remote end, before making the GET call?
I think you are getting a "handshake" request at first, where you get the chance to authenticate - that's the OPTIONS call. If you authenticate beforehand, you should get past it while testing.

Comment: I have not authenticated at the remote end. I am trying to do CRUD in Ember 3 with Rest API on server side which follow the JSON API.  For server side i follow this https://dzone.com/articles/json-api-using-katharsis-amp-spring-boot

Comment: When using CORS an OPTIONS preflight request is normal. Your server should work with that. Do you really *need* CORS? Often you dont and its just pain.

Comment: this.set('headers', {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,       Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"
    });  Set all these to header

Comment: It's called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You just need to configure your API to response to OPTIONS request. How to do this for spring was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331042/how-to-handle-http-options-requests-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @Lux   Ember is running on http://localhost:4200 and Spring boot is running on http://localhost:8889/spring-katharsis/api/departments

Comment: @Sumesh TG, i tried by setting this headers, did not solve the issue.

Comment: turn of CORS in server

Comment: why not use the ember proxy for development? `ember s --proxy=http://localhost:8889` would allow you to drop cors. The question is how your production environment will look like. But then you probably will use spring to serve ember so no CORS as well.