# How to add custom HTTP Method/Verb to Spring-MVC using @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, servlets

I need to add a custom HTTP Method/Verb to a URI. I need something like this:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/device", method = "CAPTURE")`

In short, this request needs to work
`curl -X CAPTURE http://localhost:4591/device`

It is my understanding that @RequestMapping only accepts standardized HTTP Methods, so what options do I have to achieve this.

Comment: Add method `CAPTURE` and use `HttpServlet` with Spring Boot 2.2.6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432464/2073804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You must use standardized HTTP methods.
You can create custom endpoints without HTTP method, so, every request will be accepted. (Of course, following some rules, but, isn't the topic of the question I guess)

`@RequestMapping(value = "/device")`

Or, you can use HTTP headers to allow/block requests. You just need to create a filter in your application. Something like this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, CAPTURE");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            String captureHeader = request.getHeader("CAPTURE");
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(captureHeader)) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);                   
            }else{
               chain.doFilter(req, res); 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

I guess using filter you will be able to do what you trying to do.