# Connection refused error between react and spring boot in a docker environment

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, proxy

I'm trying to run a full stack application of React JS and Spring Boot in my docker environment. Locally everything works fine. But inside the docker environment, the react js and spring boot application both starts. But I'm getting a connection refused error when I'm trying to establish communication between react and spring boot.

I've added a ProxyPass in my apache2 config file inside the docker environment as follows :- 
`ProxyPass /app-name/ http://0.0.0.0:9090/`

Error :- `OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
Docker commands used :-
Docker command to build the docker image :-
`docker build --rm -t <image-name>.`

I've exposed the ports required in the docker run command as follows :-
`docker run --rm -p 5050:8080 -p 6060:3000 --name <container-name> <image-name>`

Docker command to exec inside the container :-
`docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash`

Inside the docker environment, I started the spring boot application using 
`mvn spring-boot:run` and started the react application using `yarn install` followed by `yarn start`

How do I solve the connection refused error here?

Comment: Can you add in your question all the docker commands that you run in detail, not just container name/image ?

Comment: @Bizmate I've added the docker commands used.

Comment: did you allowed cross-origin in your spring boot application also you need to allow options method request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331042/how-to-handle-http-options-requests-in-spring-boot

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is because there is no app running on your port. You are exposing the docker local port 8080 on 5050 on the host. Have you tried http://localhost:5050?

Comment: @Bizmate you were right. All my api calls were hitting port 8080 and not 5050 and thats why I got that error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aravind glad it helped. Please mark my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is shown because you are exposing port 5050 on the host and not 8080.

Using http://localhost:5050 will work or you can run the docker command and expose the port on the host as 8080 too

`docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 6060:3000 --name <container-name> <image-name>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using separate containers for react app and spring boot app run docker inspect and be shure you are pointing to the Ip address of the container and not to localhost