# How do I use my own method with an HttpURLConnection object on Android?

Tags: java, android, http-method

According to the `void setRequestMethod (String method)` documentation here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29

The allowed methods are limited to:

- GET
- POST
- HEAD
- OPTIONS
- PUT
- DELETE
- TRACE

I have a server offering access to a list of messages and one of the options I have is to retrieve the *next* message:

```
NEXT /api/1/message
```

However, when I try to put `NEXT` as the method in the JavaScript HttpURLConnection I get an error:

> E/MsgProcessingService: Failed while handling a message: java.net.ProtocolException: Unknown method 'NEXT'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE]

Is there a non-hacky way to bypass that method limitation?

Obviously, I can create a new access point as follow on my server, but I was hoping I would not have to do that...

```
GET /api/1/message/next
```

Comment: There must be a good reason why they did not allow NEXT, I would imagine.

Comment: What version of the HTTP specification defines a `NEXT` method?

Comment: @CommonsWare WebDAV adds many other methods, why wouldn't you be able to do that with any type of web extension?!

Comment: To access a WebDAV server with WebDAV methods, you would use a WebDAV client.

Comment: @CommonsWare As you can see here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1 the method can be any valid HTTP token. Therefore `NEXT` is perfectly legal.

Comment: "Legal" does not mean that all client libraries will necessarily support it. See if there is a more forgiving HTTP client stack (e.g., OkHttp, a standalone Apache HttpClient library).

Comment: @CommonsWare My problem is the client on the Android, not the server which works just fine. I have tested with curl on the command line and in PHP and I can send the `NEXT` method and I get my JSON as expected. What is completely broken is the Android function `setRequestMethod()`...

Comment: Hence, [as I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101229/how-do-i-use-my-own-method-with-an-httpurlconnection-object-on-android?noredirect=1#comment79165628_46101229), see if there is a more forgiving HTTP client stack (e.g., OkHttp, a standalone Apache HttpClient library). This has nothing to do with Android. `HttpURLConnection` has this limitation in standard Java, as you can see from [the source code to the Java 8 edition of the class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java?av=f#314).

Answer (score 5):

No.

Those "methods" are defined in the [HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).  This method checks the String against a constant array.

As the spec says, these methods can be expanded, but it's very rare.  [The Heroku docs discuss this.](https://blog.heroku.com/expanded_http_method_support)

Related:

- How to add custom HTTP methods in Spring:  [Custom HTTP Methods in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302397/custom-http-methods-in-spring-mvc)
- Google Cloud Platform:  https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods

Comment: And yet the [HTTP documentation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1) allows for any extension... I can use any method I want in `wget`, `curl`, JavaScript... It's sad. Oh well.

Comment: Your question is about `HttpURLConnection`.  Afaik, it's not possible with that class.  There are certainly ways to do it, although I can't speak to what's available in the Android SDK.  The overwhelming recommendation seems to be not to do it.  Going against conventions is an extremely high risk choice, particularly for maintainability.