# spring REST RequestMethod how to Map a http LOCK and UNLOCK RequestMapping?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-web, http-method

seems that this is the same as [Custom HTTP Methods in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302397/custom-http-methods-in-spring-mvc)

I need to implement a call with http method LOCK and UNLOCK.

currently spring's requestMethod only supports

```
public enum RequestMethod {

    GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE

}
```

how can I implement a `@RestController` method that is called if the spring app is called with LOCK and UNLOCK http directives?

Comment: New way to do it now in Spring Boot 2.2.6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432464/2073804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using supported method ( GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE) call. Here is the way to call post method internally:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {

        final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setSupportedMethods(
            "LOCK", "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "TRACE"
        ); //here supported method

        return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new CustomHttpMethods();
    }
}
```

Custom method handler class. Here call post method internally:

```java
public class CustomHttpMethods extends DispatcherServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if ("LOCK".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            super.doPost(request, response);
        } else {
            super.service(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

Now you do requestmapping below way:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/custom")
ResponseEntity customHttpMethod(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```